# How can I get CheckBox to maintain checked state across postback in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC project with a form. In the Action method that handles the POST verb I have a custom `IModelBinder` implementation that is binding the form data to my model instance.  If there are errors I am using `bindingContext.ModelState.SetAttemptedValue()` and `bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError()` to persist the submitted value and error message to the `ModelState`.

This works great and I can see the expected behavior occurring on my input controls that are rendered with `Html.TextBox()` (which calls through to `Html.InputHelper()`).  When I use `Html.CheckBox()` (which also calls through to `Html.InputHelper()`) the state of my CheckBox is **NOT** output to th `<input />` tag.

It seems to me like the `Html.InputHelper()` method is not using the AttemptedValue from the ModelState for input fields of type CheckBox.

Here is the code from [ASP.NET MVC `Html.InputHelper()` method](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/SourceControl/FileView.aspx?itemId=288010&changeSetId=17272).

Why is it that the CheckBox attemptedValue is not output to the input tag.  Is there something I am missing here or do I need to manually handle this case by checking the ModelState and setting the tag attribute myself?

**Update 11/09**
Here is the call to `HtmlHelpers` that I am using to output the CheckBox:

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("IsDerived") %>
```

And here is the call that I am using to register the Attempted Value:

```
string isDerivedRequestValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request["IsDerived"]) ? bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.GetValues("IsDerived") [0] : null;
bindingContext.ModelState.SetAttemptedValue("IsDerived", isDerivedRequestValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve the problem or not, but since the `Html.InputHelper()` method is not checking the AttemptedValue for CheckBox controls I added the following to my controller which embeds the proper value from the `ModelState` into `ViewData` and seems to do the trick quite well.

```
ViewData["IsDerived"] = ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey("IsDerived")
                           ? bool.Parse(ViewData.ModelState["IsDerived"].AttemptedValue)
                           : false;
```

Make sure you are not explicitly setting the `isChecked` parameter value when you call `Html.CheckBox()` as that will override any value stored in `ViewData`.