# Auto Post Back Page On CheckBox Onclick

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, postback

This must be the easy one but I've been exploring for some days about how to change a row value clicking on a CheckBox. What I want is to change the value of a column clicking on the CheckBox and keep the CheckBox checked if it is true. Otherwise it will remain unchecked if false. Below is a screenshot and when Public Post column value of a row is '**No**', then the CheckBox will remain unchecked. And when I check the CheckBox, then vice-verse means it will remain checked and value will be '**Yes**'.

[image]

I am not sure how to do it exactly and seen some of the problems or links that deals with this situation:

[ASP.NET MVC submitting form on checkbox click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083100/asp-net-mvc-submitting-form-on-checkbox-click)

[How can I get CheckBox to maintain checked state across postback in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276874/how-can-i-get-checkbox-to-maintain-checked-state-across-postback-in-asp-net-mvc)

But I would like to have some more advanced ideas to implement it as it is totally different from ASP.NET Web Form. I would appreciate if experts share some ideas or helpful links to understand. Thanks.

By the way, following is the class that I am working with. I am not sure how to handle the postback from controller and so far following is done using Ajax. But it is not working or updating:

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Details can't be blank")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Date_Posted { get; set; }
    public string Time_Posted { get; set; }
    public string Time_Edited { get; set; }
    public string Date_Edited { get; set; }
    public string Public { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int User_Id { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; } //This is bit column that I am trying to change and not sure how to handle this from controller
    public List<Product> allLists;
    public IEnumerable<Product> Items;
    public Pager Pager;
}
```

Controller - HomeController.cs:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckValue(int id)
    {
        MainDbContext db = new MainDbContext();
        List result = db.Product.Find(id);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            result.Public = "Yes";
            result.Status = true;

            db.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View(db.Lists.ToList());
    }
```

View - Home/Index:

```
@model OurFirstWebApp.Models.Product
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var username = User.Identity.Name;
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.toggle').change(function () {
        //alert("Hello");
        var self = $(this);
        var url = self.data('url');
        var id = self.attr('id');
        //var value = self.prop('checked');

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { id: id },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
                $("#divData").load(window.location + " #divData");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```
<div id="divData">
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" id="data">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;">ID</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Products</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Time Posted</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Time Edited</th>
            @if (@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <th style="text-align:center;">Status</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;">Edit</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;">Delete</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;">Public Post</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td id="ID" style="text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Time_Posted)</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Time_Edited)</td>

                @if (@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <td style="text-align: center;">@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Status, new { id = item.Id, @class = "toggle", data_url = Url.Action("CheckValue", "Home") })</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Auth")/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)">Edit</a></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Auth")/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)">Delete</a></td>
                    <td id="chngData" style="text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Public)</td>

                }
            </tr>
        }
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Add a onclick script doing form.submit on each checkbox?

Comment: But I've to change the database row value from controller. Then how will I handle this?

Comment: Put the id clicked into a hidden field. Or you could use ajax submitting only the relevant part of the post to a new controller method or ......

Comment: Show the code you have tried, including your controller methods and view. If the view has been generated correctly using an `EditorTemplate` or  `for` loop, this will all be handled out of the box.

Comment: Hello Stephen Muecke! Please never mind. I can update post with the view but I am not sure how to handle the post back from the controller. Still trying to do so. Just expecting a sample if possible.

Comment: @DOTNETRocker, No one can add an answer unless you show your code.

Comment: @Stephen I've updated the post with codes and not sure why it is not working. I've used Ajax to do so. I would appreciate if you look into it and if there is anything missing.

Comment: Are you wanting to update the database each time you click on a checkbox? - So if the value of `Public` is initially "Yes" then the checkbox should be initially checked, and then if you uncheck it, you want to immediately update the database to change the value of `Public` to "No" and update the view?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. That is what I am trying to do. In the code, I passed the Id to update the specific row but seems like it is not done.

Comment: It's late here, but I will add an answer in the morning showing how to do this. But I think you have a fundamental problem have 2 properties for the same thing. You only need one database property (say) `bool IsPublic` (the name `Status` makes no sense for a `bool`) and then for display purposes, you can always use a DisplayTemplate to render "Yes" or "No" or have a `public string Public { get { return IsPublic ? "Yes" : "No"; } }` property.

Comment: Thanks to identify that. It will be great if I can do this in a single statement or property. I was just doing it for a test purpose and see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your properties `bool Status` and `string Public` are confusing and having 2 fields in the database representing the same thing is bad idea. You should have a single property (say)

```
public bool IsPublicPost { get; set; }
```

The checkbox alone should be sufficient to represent the value, but if you did want the extra column, then in the view model add an additional property (say)

```
public string PublicPostDisplayText
{
    get { return IsPublicPost ? "Yes" : "No"; }
}
```

or better, create a `DisplayTemplate` for the proeprty that outputs "Yes" or "No".

Next, you cannot correctly bind to a collection model using a `foreach` loop (refer [HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for more details) and you need to use a `for` loop or custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Product`

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Items[i].Id)</td> // see notes below
        ....
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].IsPublicPost, new { @class = "post-checkbox", data_id = Model.Items[i].Id })</td>
        // If you really want the extra column
        <td class="post-text">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Items[i].PublicPostDisplayText)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Then the script to update the database will be

```
var url = '@Url.Action("UpdatePublicPostStatus", "Home")';
$('.post-checkbox').click(function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // only if you display the extra column
    $.post(url, { id: id, isPublicPost: isChecked }, function(response) {
        if (response) {
            // no need to do anything, but if you display the extra column
            var displayText = isChecked ? 'Yes' : 'No';
            row.find('.post-text').text(displayText);
        } else {
            // Oops something went wrong - reset the checkbox and display error?
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        // Oops something went wrong - reset the checkbox and display error?
    });
});
```

and finally the controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdatePublicPostStatus(int id, bool isPublicPost)
{
    MainDbContext db = new MainDbContext();
    var product = db.Product.Find(id);
    if (product != null) // always check
    {
        product.IsPublicPost = isPublicPost;
        db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(true);
    }
    // If something went wrong, e.g. an exception, then return Json(null);
}
```

Side notes.

1. Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html (do not add then inside
   loops unless they are unique)
2. Use style sheets rather that inline styles, e.g. `td:nth-child(1) {
   text-align:center; }`
3. Using `if (ModelState.IsValid)` is pointless (and will always return
   `true`) in your case because your not posting and binding to a
   model.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But it is not updating. Do I need to include any other specific script to get it work? I've done the same as you provided.

Comment: Have you included `jquery-{version}.js`? What if any errors do you get in the browser console. Are you hitting the controller method. You need to give more details.

Comment: There are no errors and I've included the jQuery file, version - 1.10.2. But it does not update the database.

Comment: Is it hitting the controller method? (and I just noticed a typo - it should be `db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: Thanks again. I noticed that earlier and changed it according to mine.

Comment: I've tried now. I think, it is not hitting the controller.

Comment: it is not hitting the controller. I've put a breakpoint on the method.

Comment: Then your getting errors in the browser console. What are they? You need to learn the basics of debugging your code :)

Comment: I have seen the browser's console and found this: use-of-getpreventdefault-is-deprecated-use-defaultprevented-instead. I think and hope, this is not a big issue regarding the update. But still no luck to make it work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to make it work. Just took another controller and implemented perfectly. One more thing: I changed this var url = '@Url.Action("UpdatePublicPostStatus", "Home")' to var url = '@Url.Action("UpdatePublicPostStatus")'. Thanks again for guiding.